# Unable to launch "Hello World" program

Tags: java

I am learning Java from a youtuber called 'thenewboston'. I downloaded eclipse, put in a simple 'hello world' code, and now I want to run/compile the program. Whenever I click RUN however, it gives me this message:

> Unable to launch
>
> The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Here's the code:

```
class apples{
    public static void main (Sting args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello youtube!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Post your code, for starters. It's hard to help you without more information.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yfE1mXPm

Comment: How you found anything yet?

Comment: Please tell us the IDE you are using

Answer (score 5):

The problematic line is this:

```
public static void main (Sting args[])
                      //  ^-- this type is spelled "String"
```

Fix the spelling in the data type and your program should work:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hello youtube!");
}
```

Since you're new, here two hints:

- Please read the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) about the naming style: class name should start with an uppercase letter `Apples` instead of `apples`
- There is no rule for that, but you should keep the brackets at the type: `String[] args` not `String args[]`

Answer (score 0):

Also when you have that error message and the code is correct - try to change **Run Configuration** - by choosing the right application to run

Answer (score 0):

```
package AppleStuff; //depending on your package name    
class Apples{
        public static void main (String args[]){
            System.out.println("Hello youtube!");
        }
    }
```

Now if you are using Netbeans, right click and select run file. Because this a console based application or if it Eclipse click on the play button at the top bar